# Setting multiple environment variables using Puppet

Tags: puppet

Currently I am using

```
file {"/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh":
    ensure => file,
    owner => root,
    source => "puppet:///modules/java/setjvmparams.sh",
}
```

But I want to remove dependency of my module on external files. Is there a way out to set env variable?

Note: setjvmparams.sh has 3 lines.
I want to put paths in /etc/profile.d and `source` it.

Comment: Have you considered using the `content` attribute with linebreaks since this is only three lines? That would remove the external file dependency.

Comment: I used `file_line` from puppet-stdlib. Are you sure it will work with file?

Comment: If you are configuring the file to only contain these lines, then you can use `file`. If you are adding these lines to the file, then you need something else.